# 2 Web Servers (IIS8) 403 - Forbidden when viewing site root on 1 server

Tags: .net, iis, http-status-code-403

I have one website with multiple applications (.NET) on 2 servers on our Intranet.

When I try to visit [this](http://IPAddress/application1) on Server 1 I get 403 Forbidden error. (The detailed information is pointing to the DirectoryListingModule)

If I add the Default.aspx to the address above it works fine.

I went to Server 2 and tried [this](http://IPAddress/application1) and it successfully loaded up the default page fine and works.

I've gone through all the IIS settings between the sites if there is a difference I'm not spotting it.

Anyone have any idea's?